# Who has escaped the Lady of Pain's mazes and how was that escape made?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, planescape

The adventure [*Faction War*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faction_War) tells the story of Factol Rowan Darkwood and his bid to take over Sigil. As part of this plot he is imprisoned in a Maze by the [Lady of Pain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_of_Pain), but his foresight allows his quick escape. Sure, Her Serenity still came out on top, but it made me wonder: Are there other canonical escapes from Her Mazes? Or is Darkwood unique?

Examples from adventures, novels, sourcebooks, and [video games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planescape:_Torment) are welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Nameless One from Planescape: Torment *can* escape the Maze. (via a portal puzzle that doesn't appear to require any special skills/abilities, and just involves wandering around and using them in a specific order)

Of course, he IS immortal and as I recall getting sent there is optional in the first place, so it might not be present in the canon retelling of the story.

Comment: As excellent a game as *PS:T* is, officially it's not canon.

Comment: @KRyan, how is it not Canon? It's distributed by then and the IP (names & stuff) is their's so what says it's not? (Not arguing your point, just asking)

Comment: @Ben-Jamin Because it's from a licenced game and not from an official book or anything like that. I'm still counting it htough.

Comment: That is true. Though, due to its excellence, the general consensus among players is that PS:T is unofficially canon. Particularly because it doesn't change anything about the core of Planescape, it's generally harmless to consider it as such.

Answer (score 10):

Uncaged - Faces of Sigil, you meet Djhek'nlarr, A Githyanki cutter that sells maps out of the mazes. They are outlawed obviously, but the supposed dark is that she tricks burks into getting mazed by the lady, then sniffs their psychic trail to find the maze deep in the Ethereal.

Obviously, she is probably not someone you want to get known for hanging out with, but if you want an answer in game, she is a good choice.

Additionally IIRC in Pages of Pain the main character is Mazed, and makes it out.